# Test-Path returning true on empty folders

Tags: powershell, scripting

`Test-Path` is returning true, or at least appears to be on folders that are empty if they are located in the same directory as folders returning true that are NOT empty.

I've tried adjusting wildcard locations, adding additional \ to change paths to see if I could reduce the number of returned folders, but I cannot. I assumed the `foreach` portion and `Test-Path` would individually check each folder and return a result, but it appears once it sees contents, all folders thereafter are returned as true.

```cs
[int]$subDay = Read-Host "Enter days to subtract"

$date0 = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$subDay).ToString("yy") +
         ((Get-Date).AddDays(-$subDay).DayOfYear).ToString("D3")
$date1 = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$subDay).ToString("yyyy") +
         ((Get-Date).AddDays(-$subDay).DayOfYear).ToString()

$path0 = ".\11"
$path1 = ".\12"
$path2 = ".\13"

$a = $path0, $path1, $path2    

function Split {
    Param ($split)

    Split-Path -Parent $split |
        Get-Item |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
        Add-Content $archLog    

    foreach ($element in $a) {
        if (Test-Path $element\$date1\"$date0*"\*) {
            Split $element\$date1
            Split $element\$date1\"$date0*"\*
        } else { 
            Split $element\$date1
            Write-Output "Folders do not exist or are empty." |
                Add-Content $archlog
        }
    }
```

I expected the code to return folder name if it had contents, which it does. However, if an empty folder exists where a folder with contents does, both are returned. If you take away the contents of the folder, none are returned.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to write a recursive function? But you're using static variables that come from outside the function (`$a`) and undefined variables (`$date0` & `$date1`)?

Comment: The variables are defined, when posting it requests snippets of code and not everything. Dates are defined using modifications of Get-Date. The reason they are variables is because depending on the day you run it, days are subtracted to get that date, which are the folder names to check.

Comment: [mcve] not snippets of non-working code

Comment: Your problem is `Test-Path $element\$date1\"$date0*"\*` tests if there is anything in the folder `$date0\ `   it doesn't mater what is in there. It will returne `$true` if there is anything. However, how `$element`, `$date1`, `$date0` are created is not realy importent for the question.

Comment: @T-Me, that's what I want. If anything is in there, return true. However, even empty folders are coming back. Once you remove the non-empty folder, the empty ones no longer return.

Comment: where is which folder?  I can't realy imagine the folder struckture atm. Unless your problem is that you have `Split $element\$date1` in `if (Test-Path ...) { Split $element\$date1 ;  Split $element\$date1\"$date0*"\*  }`

Comment: You have 3 Pathes = `$element` if one of these has something in `$element\$date1\"$date0*"\ ` you do `Split $element\$date1` AND `Split $element\$date1\"$date0*"\* ` else you do the `else`

Comment: @T-Me The structure for each folder is the same. I will use todays date as an example... ./11/20198/19008001 is how the names would be. Each day they change. I have the two splits to get the main folder name, being 11, 12, or 13 and then the deepest folder name, being 19008001.

Comment: I see a problem with the array now. Since it's looking at just those 3 paths, once it finds a True, it returns all of the folders that exist, regardless of contents. Just not sure how to rectify that. For example, I need it to check folder X, Y and Z for contents, which would be folders. If folders 1, 2 and 3 exist in X, Y, Z, check if files exist in 1, 2 and 3. If files exist in 1, 2 and 3, return names of 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path "$element\$date1\$date0" -file -Recurse  | foreach {$_.Directory}` ? `-file` and `-Recurse` are optional. Test if they fit your needs

Comment: That tries to check the root directory and not the directories within the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186362/discussion-between-t-me-and-ethan-k).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to see every subfolder that contains a file use the parameters `-file` and  `-recurse` of the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet:

```
$a = $path0, $path1, $path2
foreach ($element in $a) { Get-ChildItem -Path $element\$date1 -file -Recurse | foreach {$_.Directory.Name} | select -uniq }
```